# Oracle- relying on ROLLBACK for data validation

Tags: oracle, transactions

Is relying on the oracle `ROLLBACK` command good practice for importing data, validating the data and THEN performing a `ROLLBACK`?

I've had a data import program built for our ERP, and looking at the code, they insert the data into the real tables, validate, and if it fails validation, they perform a ROLLBACK. I've always validated data before inserting, but just curious if this is an accepted method to rely on?

Comment: The thing is - it **cannot** guarantee that next (real) call the data wouldn't violate some constraints.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to remember here-

- Constraints enable us preserve data integrity. This means that constraints allow us to enforce business rules (or at least the most basic of those) at the database level itself.
- A `commit` or a `rollback` is a method of preserving or undoing the changes made in a transaction. If you issue a `commit` after a series of successfully run DML statements, the changes are preserved. The `rollback` statement would undo the changes.
- If, in a series of DML statements, if one of those fails, the effects of that particular statement are rolled back. E.g., if an `UPDATE` statement updates 10 rows and one of those violates a vital constraint, any of the 10 rows are not updated. Yet, the effects of its preceding statements are not implicitly rolled back.
- In order to preserve data integrity and keep the data as per the business requirements, you must issue a manual `ROLLBACK` statement if any of the DMLs fail.
- What you are seeing in your program is the same practice. It doesn't issue a `ROLLBACK` after a successful transaction, but only after a failed DML, if you look at the code closely. This is indeed a good practice to roll back on failure and commit only if everything goes right.
- Front end checks on data are indeed an essential part of any application. This ensures that the data being entered conforms to the business roles. Even in this case, constraints must be applied to perform checks at the database level. This is particularly helpful when some rookie makes changes to the front end and tries to enter invalid data. This is also helpful when someone is bypassing the application and entering data manually. Hence putting constraints on the database level is always necessary.